# Use of topicmeta in topic body

Tags: dita

I am starting to use DITA for writing product specifications. I use the "prodname" metadata to put the product number in the header. Now I am wondering how if at all I can use the same information in the body part of my document. Is there a DITA way to use this information for my purpose? Or is this not "proper" usage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a `<keyword>` element and reuse it via a key reference.

**DITA Map**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE map PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Map//EN" "map.dtd">
<map>
 <title><keyword keyref="product"/></title>
 <keydef keys="product">
  <topicmeta>
   <keywords>
    <keyword>my product</keyword>
   </keywords>
  </topicmeta>
 </keydef>
 <topicref href="topic.dita"/>
</map>
```

**DITA Topic**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE topic PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Topic//EN" "topic.dtd">
<topic id="topic">
  <title>my topic</title>
  <prolog>
    <metadata>
      <prodinfo>
        <prodname>
          <keyword keyref="product"/>
        </prodname>
      </prodinfo>
    </metadata>
  </prolog>
  <body>
    <p><keyword keyref="product"/></p>
  </body>
</topic>
```

Comment: Thank's @Stefan, that should work for both purposes. I'll try it out and get back here if it for some reason doesn't work. Thank you also for providing clear usage guidance.